# Problema con las posiciones "Y" en Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, matemáticas, pygame

durante estos días he estado trabajando en una tarea que consiste en realizar un pequeño mini juego que calcule la trayectoria de un misil disparado por un mortero, donde el usuario podrá ingresar la posición del blanco, el ángulo del mortero, la velocidad del disparo y otras cosas que no son tan necesarias para la resolución del problema que tengo.

Pasa que como Pygame trabaja con coordenadas *Y* invertidas al momento de imprimir por pantalla la trayectoria del misil, me la muestra al revés.

Las lanza de esta forma, pero la dirección debería ser al contrario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la coordenada *X* está perfecto, eso de que no salga directamente del mortero no es un problema para mí, puedo corregirlo, pero antes me gustaría que mostrase la posición de la forma que necesito.

Para lograr este resultado creé el siguiente código:

```
"La ventana es de:(1000,800)"

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                while corPosY > round(550,650):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    ventana.blit(misil_mov, (corPosX,corPosY))
                    segundero += 1
                    velX = vx(v_lanzar,angulo)
                    velY = vy(v_lanzar, angulo)
                    corPosX = round(posMisilX + velX*segundero)
                    corPosY = round(posMisilY + velY*segundero - 4.9 * segundero**2)
                    corPosY -= angulo
                    print(corPosX,corPosY)
                    pygame.display.update() 

"Donde:" 

angulo = 45
v_lanzar = 40
corPosX = 100
corPosY = 690

"Y las funciones utilizadas son:"

def vx(vel, ang):
    cos = math.cos(ang)
    movX = vel*cos
    return movX

def vy(vel, ang):
    sin = math.sin(ang)
    movY = vel*sin
    return movY

"El piso está definido en la cordenada Y = 600"
"De tal forma que el misil llega al objetivo y explota o al piso y explota"
```

Sé que mi código no está bien escrito porque es una especie de boceto.

Si alguien me puede guiar en como corregir mi código se lo agradecería mucho, estoy totalmente dispuesto a implementar sus consejos.

Comment: Podrías agregar en la pregunta el código completo de tu juego por favor?

Comment: A la hora de hacer el `blit()` (que es la instrucción que pinta el misil), cambia `corPosY` por `800-corPosY` (siendo 800 el alto de la pantalla). Probablemente tendrás que cambiar también la coordenada inicial del misil.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu disposición de ayuda. @DanteS.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda @abulafia

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tienes la función hecha para calcular la coordenada con un plano cartesiano cuya Y crece de abajo hacia arriba y la biblioteca (como casi todo en computación) trabaja con un plano cartesiano cuyo eje Y crece de arriba hacia abajo, lo que tienes que hacer es *traducir* las coordenadas entre un sistema y otro. No es tan complicado, imagina primero los dos ejes.

Llamemos a un eje, Ynt (de Y natural), y al otro, Ypc (de Y del PC), estos van como en la figura a continuación, que no está a escala ni tiene las dimensiones reales, es solo para hacerte una idea. El eje Ynt está a la derecha en rojo y el Ypc a la izquierda en negro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He omitido intencionalmente el eje X en la imagen para mantenernos enfocados en el eje Y.

Si observas con atención, teniendo en mente que tienes que encontrar al forma de *traducir* una coordenada dada en Ynt a la coordenada correspondiente en Ypc, podrás notar que se da un *fenómeno interesante*.  Para cualquier coordenada, se cumple que `Ynt + Ypc = 14`, y 14 es el alto de nuestra *vista*.

Por ejemplo:

- Cuando Ynt es 4, Ypc es 10, y 4+10=14.
- Cuando Ynt es 1, Ypc es 13, y 1+13=14.
- Cuando Ynt es 11, Ypc es 3, y 11+3=14.

Entonces, álgebra de primero de secundaria, si tenemos

```
  Ypc + Ynt = Alto
```

Y queremos obtener Ypc, podemos despejarla y nos va a quedar:

```
  Ypc = Alto - Ynt
```

Ahora si, cuando calculas la posición en Y del proyectil, puedes fácilmente traducirla a la posición Y de la vista, para dibujarlo; lo que tienes que saber de antemano es la altura de la vista.

De igual manera, si la coordenada Y en la que calculas la posición del proyectil es relativa, digamos, al piso, puedes aplicar un corrimiento, haciendo un análisis similar. Lo dejo como ejercicio, pues la idea de estos ejercicios es que desarrolles la lógica, no solo se trata de resolver el problema en cuestión, sino de forzar a nuestra mente a encontrar la solución por si misma.

Finalmente, en la gráfica de tu pregunta puedo ver que comienzas a calcular la posición del proyectil desde la base del cañón, cuando debes hacerlo desde la salida del mismo, pues dentro del cañón el proyectil no va a seguir una trayectoria parabólica. Asume que la velocidad y ángulo inicial son en el extremo final del cañón.